# What paramertization is used for Bundle Adjustment?

Tags: slam, localization, ba

You have three choices it seems for optimization when running bundle adjustment.

1. Euler Angles
2. Quaternions
3. Axis-Angle

What is the normal paramertization to use? Quaternions need to be normalized if they are used either as part of the cost function or at a minimum normalized after each update even if the jacobian doesn't include the normalization.